# Show key as localization | Vue i18n

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

Is there any solution to display the keys as localization?

I red in the documentation that I can create decision maps for fallbackLocale and my approach was to define a decision for default -> en and a decision for 'not-a-language' -> ''.

```js
new VueI18n({
  locale,
  fallbackLocale: {
    'not-a-language': '',
    default: 'en'
  },
  messages
})
```

In an event listener I set the current language to an not existing one.

```js
i18n.locale = 'not-a-language'
```

But instead of showing the key, it shows the english translation.

Answer (score 0):

### Why is this happening

When using a fallback decision map like in your case, the default decision map will always be used after the decision map for your specific locale. So the fallback chain would be: `'not-a-language' > '' > 'en'`

You can find more information here: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/fallback.html#explicit-fallback-with-decision-maps

### How to display keys

As far as I know there is no built-in way to do this specifically. But changing the locale to '' seems to do the trick.
`i18n.locale = ''`